# rxjs elegant keep fetching and accumulate while hasNextPage = true

Tags: rxjs

How to keep fetching results and accumulating them as long as pagination is active ?

I neither like the `i++` nor the side effects with `totalResults`.
This is neither elegant nor proper mapping from request to results.

Any suggestions?

```
let i = 0;
const totalResults = [];

this.http.get('url?page=' + i).pipe(
  map((data: any) => { 
    totalResults.push(...data.results)
    if(data.hasNextPage) {
      i++;
      return throwError('FetchMore');

    }
  }),
  retryWhen(
    (errors:any) => errors.pipe(
      map( (err: any) => { return err === 'FetchMore' ? of('another page available. retry') : throwError(err); }
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: `mergeScan` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't fully test it but you can try
Use `expand` to recursively call http until certain condition

```
of([0, []]).pipe(expand(([i, result]) =>
    this.http.get('url?page=' + i).pipe(
        map(res => res.hasNextPage ? [++i, result.concat[res]] : false),
    )),
    takeWhile(res => res)
)
```